# Create connection to database in VS2010 without SQL Client - dynamically

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

How to create connection to database in VS2010 without SQL Client dynamically?

I tried using `ConnectionStringSettings` and `SqlConnection` and I succeeded, but I'm not supposed to use SQL Client.

I'm using [Massive](https://github.com/robconery/massive).

Comment: Even if you're using Massive, you still need a connection string to the database.  You can provide the connection string in the app.config file ConnnectionStrings node. See:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use `System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection`.

Use a connection string like this:

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername; Pwd=myPassword;
```

Comment: Isn't this the *Native Client*? Shouldn't it be `Provider=SQLOLEDB.1`?

Comment: @Filburt I didn't use it for a long time, so I just copied it from ConnectionStrings.com, and I got the wrong one, thanks! But why the `.1`?

Comment: The .1 - weee ... you got me there - I also just copied that from the .udl file I created as described in my answer ;-) Maybe some MS star date: 2012/05/04.1

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you just miss to reference `System.Configuration` in your project and consequently *Massive* cannot find the connection string in your app.config.

Following [the instructions on github](https://github.com/robconery/massive) I could query my SQL Express database without any problems using Massive having a plain `SqlClient` connection string in my app.config.

Comment: But I'm using Microsoft Sql Server. I'm just not supposed to use the SqlClient class.

Comment: What's wrong with the SqlClient classes?  They probably have the most coverage and use of any .net access to sql.  With that much usage, it means it's solid.

Comment: @Srcee If you insist on not using SqlClient, check out @sinni800 answer using `OleDb`.

Comment: @Filburt I'm supposed to use Massive.